# How should I redefine this OWL js in Odoo 14?

Tags: javascript, odoo, dashboard

I want to override _saveDashboard Function in board_view.js

v14, Community, module board
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.  please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question. Good luck 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.